# Block selection comment for VbScript in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

How can I comment a selected block in vbscript using  Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

**Updated  :** I meant selecting a block and commenting every line. If I do it in Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 the comment created is for html, not for vbscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using my code between `<% %>` only and VS commented my selection as html, but if I use my code in between `<script language="vbscript"> </script>` and comment selection it works, it comments as vbscript code.

Answer (score 0):

use `'`

```
   <script type="text/vbscript">
    Dim myMessage
    'myMessage = "I am having a great day!"
    myMessage = "I could use a nap..."

    'This will print out myMessage to the visitor
    document.write(myMessage)

    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant selecting a block and commenting every line.
If I do it in Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 the comment created is for html, not for vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript only has support for single-line comments.

Example:

```
Dim myMessage
'myMessage = "I am having a great day!"
myMessage = "I could use a nap..."

'This will print out myMessage to the visitor
document.write(myMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy it to Notepad ++ `Ctrl+H` to open Replace. Replace `\r\n` to `\r\n'` in `Extended Search Mode` all lines will be commented with single line comment char `'`.